# Python 3.4: check if a process ends

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

I have called a subprocess in this way:

```
myProc = subprocess.Popen([args],shell=False)
```

I need to check if the subprocess ended due to an error. I didn't use `communicate()` because I don't want to actually wait for the process to end, I just need to be informed if the subprocess ended due to an error. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: So you want to be informed asynchronously about the error? Do you want to execute some  callback if there's an error, or just print something indicating that there was an error? Something else?

Comment: yes, I need to execute a callback if there's an error, but it is important not to wait for the process to finish (because it is an infinite loop), just be informed if it ends by an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by waiting on the process to end in a background thread, and executing the callback from that thread:

```
import subprocess
from threading import Thread

def async_wait(proc, cb):
    if proc.wait() != 0:
        # If you don't need a generic async_wait, you can
        # just execute whatever cb would do here,
        # and not pass it in as a separate function.
        cb(proc)

def handle_error(proc):
    print("%s failed!" % proc)

myProc = subprocess.Popen(["ls", "/asdfsd"], shell=False)
t = Thread(target=async_wait, args=(myProc, handle_error)).start()
t.start()
print("hi")
```

Output:

```
hi
ls: cannot access /asdfsd: No such file or directory
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x7f26d8c70210> failed!
```